# Project stops working when I sign it and export as app Bundle or APK

Tags: android, flutter, google-play, android-app-bundle, app-bundle

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0tKdv.jpg)I recently did a project in flutter for a company, at the moment I am trying to deliver the project to upload the app on google play, to upload the app google play asks me that I have to upload the application as a signed app bundle, I do all the process and upload the app, passing the app to this format compresses the project by more than 90%, by the time the review is finished and the app is available, by the time I download it and start using it, nothing works, the app runs but at the moment to log in, it is not possible or it shows an error, the funny thing is that if I do not sign the app and convert it directly into an unsigned apk and install it on my device, everything works correctly, does anyone know what this could be due to?

The only thing that has worked for my project to work correctly is not to sign the project, but since it is not signed I cannot upload it

I have already done everything possible, and after reviewing everything, I confirm that firebase firestore only stops working after signing the project in android studio, I have carried out different tests generating signed and unsigned apks, and it only stops working when it is signed, The biggest problem is that to upload my project on Google Play it must be signed

The error that appears when trying to access the firestore information is: Error: Null check operator used on a null value

Comment: What feature is not working properly?
Are all packages up to date? Could it be that a package you are using is incompatible with the Android version?

Comment: The project works correctly, it stops working when I click the project to upload it to google play, so far I have only noticed that the firebase auth does not work, since I do not go through the login I do not know what else is failing

Comment: Are you using obfuscation? Try without obfuscating. Also, try adding some logs so that you can debug it.

Comment: could you send the error you are getting?

Comment: I have already done everything possible, and after reviewing everything, I confirm that firebase firestore only stops working after signing the project in android studio, I have carried out different tests generating signed and unsigned apks, and it only stops working when it is signed, The biggest problem is that to upload my project on Google Play it must be signed

The error that appears when trying to access the firestore information is: Error: Null check operator used on a null value